# Error: Nothing returns when running which python on terminal

Tags: python, macos, installation

I'm trying to install Python.
When I do $ brew install python
Warning: python-2.7.10 already installed
But when I put which python It returns nothing
Please help

Comment: It is already installed on OSx. Can you search for the basic development environment for Python called IDLE? Try running that.

Comment: Could you paste the contents of your PATH? Run `echo $PATH` in a terminal.

Comment: Did you re-open your terminal in order to make sure that the additional PATH-variable just exported resp. your new `.bash_profile` has been reloaded?